# Error Expected ']' before token-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C. I am getting errors when declaring `char tempbuf[RMH_EVENT+1];`
where `RMH_EVENT` is a macro containing the value `60`. Why is it showing me the error ?
I have declared another char above it as `char buf[512];` in the same way as I declared the tempbuf, but it's not showing me any error.

Comment: Why is this in a blockquote? Who are you quoting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the source it's hard to tell what the problem is, but I'm guessing you probably did something like this:

```
#define RMH_EVENT 60;
```

instead of:

```
#define RMH_EVENT 60
```

Comment: I have put it with semicolon.Thanks..After removing the semicolon it doesnt show me any error.

Comment: Good catch @Paul R, its easy to put the semicolon in #define's !